# how to create a tailwind responsive class using a plugin

Tags: tailwind-css

how can I reproduce the following scss using a plugin?

```
.large-title {
    font-family: $font-family-2;
    @apply leading-none; 
    color: $large-title-color;
    @apply uppercase;

    @apply text-xl;

    // I don't know how to add these in the plugin
    @apply sm:text-2xl;
    @apply md:text-3xl;
    @apply lg:text-4xl;
    @apply xl:text-5xl;
}
```

in my config file, I currently have:

```
module.exports = {
[...]
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    plugin(function({ addBase, config }) {
      addBase({
        '.large-title': { 
          fontFamily: [config('theme.fontFamily.family-2')],
          fontSize: config('theme.fontSize.xl'),
          lineHeight: config('theme.lineHeight.none'),
          color: config('theme.colors.primary.900'),
          textTransform: 'uppercase',
        },
      })
    })
  ],
}
```

The only thing missing is I can't find out how to add the responsive size changes from the class in the plugin.

Comment: Maybe this can help: [Referencing the user's config](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#referencing-the-user-s-config)

Answer (score 3):

One way to add `@media` queries to a class in [Tailwind's CSS-in-JS syntax](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#css-in-js-syntax) is nesting:

```
addBase({
  '.large-title': { 
    '@media (min-width: 500px)': {
      fontSize: theme('fontSize.xl'),
    }
  },
})
```

Additionally, user's breakpoints can be accessed using the `theme()` function:

```js
const sm = theme('screens.sm', {})
```

Combining these two snippets you could:

```js
const sm = theme('screens.sm', {})

addBase({
  '.large-title': { 
    `@media (min-width: ${sm})`: {
      fontSize: theme('fontSize.xl'),
    }
  },
})
```

One caveat to be aware of in case you're building this plugin for public use is that a user may entirely change their `theme.screens` config. If a user removes the `theme.screens.sm` key from their configurations, for example, the snippet above would no longer work.

Comment: You have a JavaScript syntax error near `@media (min-width: ${sm})`. It must be quoted in `[]`, as a JavaScript object key, since that's a template string.